# How to start an Intent if context is not Activity Context but Application Context

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

I'm trying to start an activity from a class that extends BroadcastReceiver.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
```

the problem is that parameter context is the Application context and not an Activity context.

Is there a way start an intent using the Application context?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here is sample code how to call another activity using context,
set flag as per your requirement:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    
    Intent intent = new Intent();   
    intent.setClass(context, xxx.class); 
    intent.setAction(xxx.class.getName()); 
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS); 
    context.startActivity(intent);  
}
```

Comment: This answer, while works, is vague in answering the question.
In order to call startActivity with application context, include the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
Also think about changing the name from context to appContext so it is clear which context you expect.

Comment: Why do we need to provide the NEW_TASK flag? Because I tried starting an activity from an app context _without_ this flag, and it worked fine.