# How to start an Intent for an Application Context

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

I found almost the same question:[How to start an Intent if context is not Activity Context but Application Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237448/how-to-start-an-intent-if-context-is-not-activity-context-but-application-contex)

but I faild to do it when using https://stackoverflow.com/a/9238105/6593395

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(action)) {
        Intent applicationIntent = new Intent(context, myCamApplication.class);
        applicationIntent.setAction(myCamApplication.class.getName());
        applicationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(applicationIntent);
```

the error log:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.fenchtose.asyncamera/com.eason.mycamera.myCamApplication}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I have registered this myCamApplication class as my application class inside AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application
    android:name=".myCamApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootComplete"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity
        android:name=".myCam"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

So, Anyone could help?

Comment: Could you include your code? This way it would be easier to help you

Comment: Have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Christopher yes, I have included the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Marat please have a look, thanks

Comment: new Intent(context, myCamApplication.class); is wrong, you need to provide Activity class here

Comment: @ViktorYakunin , so how to start an Application context using Intent?

Answer (score 2):

You can not start an Application class. You can only start an Activity.

Change your code from e.g.:

```
Intent applicationIntent = new Intent(context, myCamApplication.class);
```

to

```
Intent applicationIntent = new Intent(context, myCam.class);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, here is a similiar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237448/how-to-start-an-intent-if-context-is-not-activity-context-but-application-contex

Comment: I'm not sure, what are you trying to achieve? There is no way to start an Application-class via startActivity!

Comment: I want to do something only one time in the Application's contructor when boot commpleted

Comment: I think the application-class is already instantiated, if your BroadcastReceiver gets a message? Otherwise you won't have an context instance, or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create an other Activity and add it to your `Manifest.xml` and see if there's any error do not forget to add  this code `<activity android:name=".yourSecondActivity" />` and start a new `Intent`

Comment: I could succeed to start an activity context by context.startActivity.
but couldn't do it for an Application class

Comment: did you use `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, yourSecondActivity.class);MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);` ???

Comment: I have included the code, please have a look, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you don't understand basic principles. In android you have only 4 components: Activity, Service, ContentProvider, BroadcastReceiver. So in your manifest you declare that you have Application (name, attributes...) and inside the application you have Activities, Services, Receivers, ContentProviders.

Your application is not your Application class. So to start your application you should start default activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);//because we use Application context
startActivity(intent);
```

P.S. Your Application class will start automatically. Lifecycle of application is following:
Start of Application class -> Start of Component(service, activity..) -> Stop of Component(service...) -> Stop of Application class

P.S.S.
There is no need to check the action in onReceive - it will be there for the only reason:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
```