# Xposed: How to get the hooked app's context?

Tags: android, xposed

Like the title, I want to hook a third app, and can call my application activity from the third app's activity.So I want to get the third app's context, how should I do?

The third app's package is `com.ss.android.gallery.heavy`, My project's package is `com.example.hao.hookstartupinterfacetest`;

My Xposed Module.java(MainActivity here is my project's activity)

```
XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("com.ss.android.gallery.heavy.activity.SplashActivity",
                loadPackageParam.classLoader, "getMainIntent", new XC_MethodReplacement() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object replaceHookedMethod(MethodHookParam methodHookParam) throws Throwable {
                        Context context = (Activity)methodHookParam.getResult();
                        return new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    }
                });
```

The SplashActivity.class (It is in the third app, MainActivity here belongs to the third app.)

```
   public class SplashActivity extends BaseSplashActivity{
       protected Intent getMainIntent(){
           return new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
       }
   }
```

Error

```
01-18 20:38:23.669 4730-4730/com.ss.android.gallery.heavy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ss.android.gallery.heavy, PID: 4730
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.ss.android.gallery.heavy/com.example.hao.hookstartupinterfacetest.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
        at com.ss.android.gallery.base.activity.BaseSplashActivity.goMainActivity(BaseSplashActivity.java:61)
        at com.ss.android.gallery.base.activity.BaseSplashActivity.access$000(BaseSplashActivity.java:17)
        at com.ss.android.gallery.base.activity.BaseSplashActivity$1.run(BaseSplashActivity.java:76)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
```

Comment: [AndroidAppHelper.currentApplication](http://api.xposed.info/reference/android/app/AndroidAppHelper.html#currentApplication())

Comment: Hi, you are great, I solve the problem, but it cannot call my app's activity.Do you know the principle?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please edit your question and add the code and any errors that you are having problems with.

Comment: I'm going to guess you're trying to start your activity using the application context. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237448/how-to-start-an-intent-if-context-is-not-activity-context-but-application-contex

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to start your app's activity directly using the context of the hooked app, which doesn't work since that activity is not actually part of the hooked app (hence the "not defined in AndroidManifest.xml" error). You must explicitly specify your app package and the full name of the class when you create your intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(
    // Your app's package name
    "com.example.hao.hookstartupinterfacetest",
    // The full class name of the activity you want to start
    "com.example.hao.hookstartupinterfacetest.MainActivity");
return intent;
```

You should also set the `android:exported` property of your `MainActivity` to `true` inside your `AndroidManifest.xml`, so that it can be started by the hooked app.

Also, `Context context = (Activity)methodHookParam.getResult();` should probably be `Context context = (Activity)methodHookParam.thisObject;`, though you don't actually need it at all with this method.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to start a activity from a hooked method you can use the following code.

Note: The answer is based on my understanding of question ( I did not understand English from the question ). Please comment below before down voting.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.hao.hookstartupinterfacetest", "com.example.hao.hookstartupinterfacetest.MainActivity"));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
AndroidAppHelper.currentApplication().startActivity(intent);
```

if you want to get context of third party app.
You can cast the param.thsobject to Activity.

```
Activity activity = (Activity) param.thisobject;
```

then you can use

```
activity.getApplicationContext();
```

make sure that the class ( which you are hooking ) is an instance of Activity otherwise you cant cast param.thisobject to Activity.
Hope it helps.