# java.lang.RuntimeException at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

Tags: android, runtimeexception

From Google Play Console,
`java.lang.RuntimeException` occurs without "**Caused by:**"

The below log is copied from Google Play Console Crash log.
This is for: Android 8.0, Android 8.1, Android 7.0, Android 7.1

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2955)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3030)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1696)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Please help me regarding this!

Comment: Can you please provide us the code at the activity which causes the error?

Comment: It occurs on dozens of terminals per 140,000 units.

Comment: I do not know which activity it is.

Comment: send the code about the suspicious activity

Comment: `RunTimeException: <BR>`... not sure what it's referring to as `<BR>`... Any activities/XML that mention that tag?

Comment: i think @Nilesh Rathod has edited your question or the google play console has done this to create line break between the log

Comment: It does not occur in the self-test but only in the Google play console.
So I can not find out what the activity is and can not fix it.

Comment: @San Moohak, You can find the caused class name from "heading" of "ANRs & Crashes" page of your crash.

Comment: The same happened for me as well upload obfuscation file, to play store

Answer (score 6):

`ActivityThread.java` says it's [updatePendingConfiguration()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#2948) or [registerOnActivityPausedListener()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#3026), so it either fails with `.onPause()` or it fails to call the `super()` method with the correct arguments - or something is wrong with the `Configuration` being applied.

I'd glady explain how to solve the issue, but the question lacks the code which throws the exception. The best way to tackle this might be to employ something alike [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics), so that one can see where exactly this is coming from and which devices are affected (in case this should be specific). I'd almost suspect that it might be caused by starting an `Activity` with the application's `Context`, while not setting flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` (see: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9238105/549372)).

Answer (score 1):

From analyzing the log following assumption can be made,

> The exception is thrown in any of the external libraries
>   used in the project

**Explanation:** Basically, the exception is thrown by `ActivityThread.java`, more specifically, the `performLaunchActivity()` method at line `2955` threw the exception. As the stack trace didn't include any of your application's **internal** `class`, we can assume that the exception is thrown in an **external** `class` that is shipped with a library you are using in your project.

If that is the case, following workarounds can be performed to sort this out -

- Look into all the library dependencies and markdown suspected ones
- If you are using a custom view (such as AdView) from an external library, that library is most likely to cause this crash
- Upgrade all the 3rd party libraries to latest version since the crash is causing in the latest OSs
- Look into the official documentation to correctly implement those libraries. Like, troubleshoot page of the SDK's website may have the solution to this exact issue. Like, **Dynamsoft Camera SDK** already addressed this issue [here](https://blog.dynamsoft.com/dws/android/How-to-solve-the-issue-with-LitePal)
- Look into the issue tracker of the libraries for this issue. For example, **Android-Permission** library has a [closed issue](https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions/issues/1) having exactly the same log.
- If your project is **react native**, there is a long discussion about it [here](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-screens/issues/17)

**Suggestion**: I want to add few more lines with @Martin Zeitler's suggestion of using [Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics).

> I recommend you to [Customize your Firebase Crashlytics crash
>   reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android). Because, sometimes only stack trace is not enough to reproduce the
>   crash.

By using the customization feature you will be able to get,

- User's identity
- State of the app
- The Events that were performed before the crash

Which will surely help you regenerate the crash and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error. I solved it, maybe it helps some people:

The problem was in my land/tooldbar.xml. I have migrated to Androidx library. I solved my problem changing problematic xml files.

**Do not use:**
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
....
....

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

**Instead use:**
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
....
....
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

Comment: This shouldn't even have compiled, therefore this seems quite unlikely.

Comment: @MartinZeitler It may be compiled because I tried in portrait smarpthones.(Because **land/toolbar.xml** was problematic) Besides, I was not rotating my smartphone when I test it. 

As a result, it seems that no problem in my **portrait** phones but when I look Dev Console, thousands of error I saw. 

Finally, the solution is this.

Comment: @gurkanstack as you describe that, the linter should have warned about "inconsistent layouts"... as well as throwing a `ClassNotDefException`, which certainly breaks the build (unless providing both dependencies, without having had the jetifier enabled).

Comment: @gurkanstack I hope my suggestion of updating all the library and correctly implementing them by reading official documentation, helped you sort this out. I have also updated my answer by adding a suggestion about customizing crashlytics so that you can deal with this kind of issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

### Intro

For the people saying:

```
did you resolve this issue? It's a rising crash in my app as well – Bao Le Feb 6 at 8:36 
did anybody resolve this issue? – AwaisMajeed Feb 9 at 13:15 
Also happening to me. =( – masterlopau Feb 26 at 1:51
do this solved? – Vengat Jul 19 at 5:55
```

Do **YOU** have the extra **cause** log ? It would help enormously.

### This is your Crash log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2955)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3030)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1696)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

### Compare with this Crash log (identical line numbers and code flow):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2955)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3030)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1696)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

This line differs:

```
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
```

and:

```
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0 (Native Method)
```

### with the extra cause log:

```
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.i$b: 
  at android.support.v4.app.i.instantiate (Fragment.java:386)
  at android.support.v4.app.k.a (FragmentContainer.java:33)
  at android.support.v4.app.s.a (FragmentState.java:79)
  at android.support.v4.app.o.a (FragmentManager.java:3080)
  at android.support.v4.app.l.a (FragmentController.java:152)
  at android.support.v4.app.j.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:330)
  at host.exp.exponent.experience.f.onCreate (ReactNativeActivity.java:140)
  at host.exp.exponent.experience.a.onCreate (BaseExperienceActivity.java:79)
  at host.exp.exponent.experience.ExperienceActivity.onCreate (ExperienceActivity.java:160)
  at host.exp.exponent.experience.ShellAppActivity.onCreate (ShellAppActivity.java:22)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7174)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1220)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2908)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0 (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:334)
  at android.support.v4.app.i.instantiate (Fragment.java:364)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at abi30_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.screens.Screen$ScreenFragment.<init> (Screen.java:19)
```

**NOTE** the at **`android.support.v4.app`** lines.

See [Android standalone app randomly crashes on app open](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2391)

### Fixes

### android.support class packages, or have a *Compat suffix

### (1) [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)

(i) This problem has a miriad of causes from my internet search. A common cause seems to be the use of `android.support class packages`, or having a `*Compat suffix`. **Review** you `build.gradle` files for `android.support.v4` etc...

(ii) Because *sometimes* it does not occur in testing, only deployment I guess the `android.support.v4` etc... use's a problematic device library on some devices or API's.

> - Note: With the release of `Android 9.0 (API level 28)` there is a new
>     version of the support library called AndroidX which is part of
>     Jetpack. The `AndroidX` library contains the existing support library
>     and also includes the latest `Jetpack` components.
> - You can continue to use the support library. Historical artifacts
>     (those versioned `27` and earlier, and packaged as `android.support.*`)
>     will remain available on `Google Maven`. However, all new library
>     development will occur in the `AndroidX` library.
> - We recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects. You
>     should also consider migrating existing projects to `AndroidX` as well.
>     [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup)
> - The support libraries are now available through `Google's Maven`
>     repository. We no longer support downloading the libraries through the
>     `SDK Manager`, and that *functionality will be removed soon..*
> - Note: After including the Support Library in your application project,
>     we strongly recommend that you **shrink**, **obfuscate**, and **optimize** your
>     app for release. In addition to protecting your source code with
>     obfuscation, shrinking removes unused classes from any libraries you
>     include in your application, which keeps the download size of your
>     application as small as possible.
> - Note: If you are including several support libraries, the minimum SDK
>     version must be the highest version required by any of the specified
>     libraries. For example, if your app includes both the `v14` `Preference`
>     Support library and the `v17` `Leanback` library, your minimum SDK version
>     must be `17` or higher.

See also:

[Support Library Packages](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages)

[features](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features)

### (2) react-native-screens

> It is related to react-native-screens and they have workaround for
>   this issue, please have a look at:

[Android crashes nondeterministically when restoring from background](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-screens/issues/17) - veedeo.

Answer (score -1):

This crash could happen from literally anything. I had the same issue and the root cause was an `IllegalArgumentException` thrown by an incorrectly implemented `Comparator` within an overridden `Fragment#onViewCreated`. The fragment itself was added during `AppCompatActivity#onCreate` via `FragmentManager`.

```
2020-01-03 15:38:33.001 7860-7860/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 7860
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.app:layout/my_activity: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.app:layout/my_activity: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.app:layout/my_activity: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.app:layout/my_activity: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.app:layout/my_activity: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:777)
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:514)
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:441)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245)
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1492)
        at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1470)
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:206)
        at com.example.app.MyFragment.onViewCreated(MyFragment.java:188)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1144)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:851)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1133)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1393)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3205)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:134)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:336)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:656)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
2020-01-03 15:38:33.003 7860-7860/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
```

Of course, it's almost impossible to find the root cause if you just have the crash report from Google Play Console. I had the luck to have a customer incident, giving me insights on where to look and how to reproduce the crash. You might also switch to a **custom crash reporting tool** like HockeyApp or Firebase to see the whole stacktrace.

Comment: Your log is totally different and absolutely unrelated to this problem

Answer (score -1):

Upload the deobfuscation(mapping.txt) file to Google playstore.
Read the following document on how to generate and upload.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=en